# Quickest method to sell everything

Tags: openttd

I've built up a huge empire and have accumulated a sufficient fortune, but unfortunately (accidental pun) my empire is built on by-gone technologies that are limiting my profit potential (though it be the year 2022, my transport system is based primarily on rail, using far outdated engines).

Though the auto-replace feature makes upgrading my road vehicles easy, they are merely auxiliary to my train network which can not be upgraded so easily (I will have to rebuild all the track and stations and depots with monorail)

I've also found some deficiencies with my network on a very deep rooted, structural level, and am now looking to start over - removing all of my constructions and establishments whilst maintaining my wealth (rather than starting a new game).

Doing this the conventional way (the bulldozer) will take hours of tedious work, and I can't merely drag the bomb across the map (it would destroy the cities of which I've shaped the growth, and surely destroy my company's reputation).

What is the fastest approach to doing this kind of thing?
Will I have to send all my vehicles to depots, then sell them, then the depots, then all the stations and tracks?
Is there a button somewhere to do it all for me, or some kind of shortcut I can take?
Any bright ideas could save me a lot of time and work!

The people of Lartown thank you!
[image: Lartown]

Comment: It's a long time since I've played openttd so I may be wrong, but can you destroy the company and transfer all your wealth to a new company?

Comment: I saved my map, opened it in multiplayer, opened a new game client, made a new company and tried to transfer the money, but half of it disappeared. Then all of it. But when I destroyed the first company, $80M came back. I can live with that. It successfully destroyed all my constructions (except roads, of course), so I thank you! :)

Comment: Oops. Putting the map back on single player just lost all the money. I don't know how this works. Ah crap.

Comment: That's odd, I can't remember any mechanisms in game for money simply disappearing :S

Comment: You could try destroying your current company, and then using cheats to give your new company the correct amount of money? http://wiki.openttd.org/Cheats#Increase_money_by_.C2.A310.2C000.2C000

Comment: I might as well start a new game and use cheats! It's not the same :'(

Comment: The fastest way might be to just bulldoze bit by bit.  That gives you the added advantage of updating your routes piecemeal, rather than reconstructing them from scratch.  Those routes that have structural issues might be more complicated to fix, though.

Comment: It'd probably be easier just to reset the game. That'd get rid of everything pretty damn quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Can't you do a track conversion? I'm sure there is a tool that lets you convert from one track type to another?

http://wiki.openttd.org/Convert_rail

Comment: which one might that be?

Comment: @axrwkr It's a button that looks like a piece of track with a looping arrow over the top of it.  On that link above, it's the right most button on the toolbar.
Basically, you select what track type you want to convert to, then click the convert button and drag it over the track you want to convert.

Comment: And you can also convert the trains by converting the depot. drive train to depot -> sell train -> upgrade depot -> buy new train. The new train should have the same orders as the one you just sold.

Answer (score 2):

**Destroying your current network**

Towns won't allow you to destroy more than a couple buildings before dropping their rating too low, even from the maximum of '1000' rating. It's also quite easy to get enough rating back to build a new station by building trees.

Dragging the bulldoze tool across the map after having sold all your trains or put them in depots is thus quite an effective way of quickly getting rid of your network.

Keep in mind that bulldozing water can get quite expensive. You can hold down the **SHIFT** key when doing any building or terraforming operation to check how much a that operation will cost in openTTD without executing it.

**Upgrading an existing network**

I've often had to do this in my games. First off, things become a lot less painful if you have made use of the 'groups' system to group all your collections of trains that have the same orders. However, it still features quite a bit of manual steps with default openTTD installations.

If you have not, then I advise you to make a group for each of those collections. You can do this in the [vehicle list](https://wiki.openttd.org/Vehicle_lists). It's a bit of organizing that pays off managing your network later. Groups can also have [shared orders](https://wiki.openttd.org/Orders) which means if you change the orders of one train in the group, all the others will copy your changes.

Then, order all your trains to move to their depots from the same vehicle list by selecting 'all vehicles' then 'manage list' to 'go to depot'. Depending on the amount of depots, the size of your network, and the speed of your vehicles as well as your game settings it may take anywhere between a few months to several years of in-game time before all trains are situated in a depot.

Then, you can start upgrading all your rail with the 'convert rail' tool, except for the depots, to monorail or maglev. It can be found in the rail construction menu.

Afterwards, we can build the new trains. For each of your rail groups, do the following, assuming you're upgrading to maglev (otherwise replace 'maglev' with 'monorail'):

1. Find the station that's first on the order list of an old train.
2. Build a new maglev depot near the station.
3. Manually create a single maglev train that matches the railway train.
4. Open up the orders menu. Hold down the **CTRL** key and click on the existing old train in the train list.
5. Check that the maglev train has copied orders from the existing train.
6. Now click the 'clone' button in the depot, hold down the **CTRL** key again (for shared orders) and clone your new maglev train any number of times you want. I advise cloning 1 maglev train for every 2 railway trains you had previously, as they are quite a bit faster, more powerful, and carry more cargo.

There are some newGRFs that can make the process a bit less of a chore. I'd recommend you look into [Universal Railtype depots](https://www.tt-forums.net/viewtopic.php?t=50041) that can support trains of every rail type. With these you can replace railway vehicles with maglev vehicles using autoreplace.

If you're playing on a multiplayer server that spans multiple railway types in its time period, consider recommending this type of newGRF to the admins. It can be configured so that the universal railtype has a speed penalty (e.g. a max speed of say 50 kph) so it can't easily be abused and is only used for depots for type switching without having to have amazing apm to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

There was a cheat for this in Transport Tycoon Deluxe, where you could make a sign and put `Cht: Tracks 1 2` to convert all your rail to monorail or `Cht: Tracks 1 3` to convert from rail to maglev.

I'm not sure if this is in OpenTTD, but it might be worth a shot. At least then you'd only have to do some minor network restructuring, rather than rebuilding the whole lot.